# Run a Python script on every text file in a folder using Spyder

Tags: python, file, syntax, spyder, delete-row

I am trying to run a script onto over 900 files using the Spyder platform, that aims to delete the first 3 rows of data and certain columns. I tried looking into other similar questions but was unable to achieve the intended results.

My code for one text file  is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 
mydataset = pd.read_csv('vectors_0001.txt')
df = pd.DataFrame(mydataset)
df.drop(df.iloc[:,:2], inplace = True, axis = 1)
df.drop([0,1,3], axis = 0, inplace = True)
df = df.dropna(axis = 0, subset=['Column3','Column4'])
```

Then I want to modify the code above so it can be applied to the consecutive text files, all the text file names are: vectors_0001, vectors_0002, ..., vectors_0900. I tried to do something similar but I keep getting errors. Take the one below as an example:
(Note: that 'u [m/s]', 'v [m/s]' are the columns I want to keep for further data analysis and the other columns I want to get rid of.)

```
import glob
import os.path
import sys
import pandas as pd

dir_of_interest = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_of_interest, "*.txt"))
for file in files: 
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f: 
        f.writelines(3:)
df = pd.read_csv("*.txt")
df_new = df[['u [m/s]', 'v [m/s]']  
df_new.to_csv('*.txt', header=True, index=None)
    with open('file.txt','r+') as f: 
        print(f.read())
```

However I tried to run it and I got the error:

```
 f.writelines(3:)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I really want to get this figured out and move onto my data analysis. Please and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure of what you are trying to achieve here but you're using the writelines functions incorrectly. It accepts a list as an argument

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_writelines.asp

You're giving it "3:" which is not valid. Maybe you want to give it a fraction of an existing list ?

Comment: I tried changing the: "f.writelines(3:)" to "f.writelines(f.readlines()[3:])" it somehow worked, but now I'm getting another error:                                                                df_new.to_csv('*.txt', header=True, index=None)                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax